# Debugging an Interface with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, interface, breakpoints

I do have a problem and I searched for a solution for a very long time now, but did not find anything. Problem is: I do have a java-program, and I want to debug it. I have set a couple of break points in one of the methods i need to debug, but eclipse seems to just skip them when i run the debugger.
I am sorry that i cannot provide any code here, because I do not have the permission to share it on the internet. But I can describe it's structure:
The method where i put my break points is inherited from an interface. Is this the reason why the debugger does not see the break points? Does it stop at the declaration of the method in the interface, and not look into the implementation itself?

Really guys I am frustrated about this. I am sure there is an easy solution for this, but I can't figure it out. And I have checked that the program really reaches the code in the method ;)

Thank you a lot in advance!

UPDATE:
I have put a try-catch-block into the code where my breakpoints seem to fail, and print the stack trace to the console: It catches an error in a line where I do have a breakpoint. I have no idea what is wrong here.

Comment: The interface should have little to do with this. I'm not sure how this question can be answered without code. I suggest that you try to produce a small program with similar code that we can run, compile and test, and try to debug that reproduces your problem, a [minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Have you enabled global debugging.

Comment: I am just assuming, are you doing "Step In" or just "Step Over" while debugging?

Comment: No it won't come to any stepping, the program runs through and won't stop ;)
I'll check the other hints and report back soon

Comment: My guess is that method where you put the BP is never called. Put a `System.out.println()` there to make sure it is called. Also interfaces are not inherited by a class but implemented.

Comment: Are you setting the breakpoint in the Interface or the implementing class? And you're certain you're launching using Debug rather than Run?